# Why are the Entire object attributes are being displayed when printing through a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a 5x5 board that has various characters stored in different positions, to signify it's empty, a '-' is displayed and depending on the character another symbol is displayed %,& etc.

I'm able to assign the character to the position, but when it comes to displaying the board, the toString() method is printed out as apposed to the symbol as desired using the `getSymbol()` method.

Characters are stored in a `characters` array and the board is held in 2D array`multD`.
`Character` is a parent class, subclasses are `Dog`, `cat` etc.

Main Method

```
Object [][] multD = new Object[5][5];
ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();

Character dog1 = new Dog();
dog1.setPosition(2, 2);
multD[dog1.getX()][dog1.getY()] = dog1;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        if (multD[i][j] == null){
            multD[i][j] = '-';
        }else  {
            multD[i][j]=("@@");  //test
          //multD[i][j] = multD[i][j].getSymbol();<- something I assumed like this but I don't know the code
        }
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        System.out.print(multD[i][j]+" ");
        System.out.println();
}
```

Dog Subclass (more attributes will be added)

```
public class Dog extends Character{
private int x, y;

    public Dog(){
        setType("Dog");
        setSymbol('%');
    }
    @Override
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    @Override
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    @Override
    public void setPosition(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

toString Method in the `Character` Parent Class

```
   public String toString() {      
       String st = "Entity Properties \n";
       st = st + "  TYPE:  " + getType() ;
       return st;
   }
```

Now that the Dog is stored in [2][2], how do I print just the Symbol of that character? Eventually the characters will move.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`Object [][] multD = new Object[5][5];`

need to be modified to

`Character [][] multD = new Character[5][5];`

if you want to call `getSymbol()` on `multD`.

Comment: I originally used this idea but when I wanted to display - in the null fields, it wasn't allowed as 'char cannot be converted to type Character'

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is coming from this line:

```
System.out.print(multD[i][j]+" ");
```

This is because you're concatenation a `String` to an `Object`, so the JVM calls `.toString()` on the object. What you probably want to do is this, instead:

First, refactor your program to change `multD` from an `Object[][]` to a `Character[][]`. Then, change the line above to this:

```
System.out.print(multD[i][j].getSymbol()+" ");
```

Note that you'll need to add a `null`-check as well, or this will throw a `NullPointerException`. That could look something like this:

```
System.out.print((multD[i][j] == null ? "-" : multD[i][j].getSymbol())+" ");
```

(The `condition ? expression : expression` syntax is called the 'ternary operator'. Information about it can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).)

Assuming that you want `null` to be converted to `-`.

I'd also recommend defining a default type to populate the array with (e.g. `Empty extends Character`).

You might also want to make Character an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) or [abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) instead, as you don't seem to ever instantiate a plain `Character`, just its subclasses. It'd be a bit more work, though, and your approach works as well.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing and understanding this line `System.out.print((multD[i][j] == null ? "-" : multD[i][j].getSymbol())+" ");`

Comment: It's a ternary operator. I'll edit in an explanation when I'm back at my computer, but a simple Google search for the term should give you a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a `getSymbol()` method on the `Character` class and store the symbol on the `Character` class.

Then, you can either call the array element such as `multD[i][j].getSymbol()` or you can implement a `toString()` method on the `Character` class that simply returns a call to `getSymbol`. Then, simply calling `multD[i][k]` will return the Symbol.

Comment: I have both a setter and getter for the symbol in the character class, but when printing through the array, It returns the entire attributes as before

Comment: You need to also implement a `toString()` method on the `Character` class, or else you'll only get the default `toString()` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

multD must be an array of `Character`. Use/keep `null` for empty fields. When printing, access the Symbol of Character via its getter.

```
Character [][] multD = new Character[5][5];
ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();

Character dog1 = new Dog();
dog1.setPosition(2, 2);
multD[dog1.getX()][dog1.getY()] = dog1;


for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        if (multD[i][j] == null) {
            System.out.print("- ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(multD[i][j].getSymbol() + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I've just realised I'm not actually using the ArrayList characters to store the entities. Is it possible to store them in both and use something like `for(int i=0; i<characters.length; i++){
        System.out.println(characters.toString());
    }` to display all information about the entities stored in the table?

Comment: Yes, you can just add `characters.add(dog1);` to also have the same `dog1` object in the characters list too. Also your for() to print the information will work fine as you have already implemented Character.toString() accordingly.